# Multiplication of two ints overflowing to result in a negative number

Tags: java, integer, overflow

Consider this snippet from the Java language specification.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1000000;
        System.out.println(i * i);
        long l = i;
        System.out.println(l * l);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
-727379968
1000000000000
```

Why is the result `-727379968` for `(i*i)`? Ideally it should be 1000000000000.

I know the range of Integer is from –2147483648 to 2147483647. so obviously 1000000000000
is not in the given range.

Why does the result become `-727379968`?

Answer (score 11):

Java (like most computer architectures these days) uses something called [*two's complement arithmetic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which uses the most significant bit of an integer to signify that a number is negative. If you multiply two big numbers, you end up with a number that's so big it sets that highest bit, and the result ends up negative.

Comment: so curious, why did Java library decide to show a negative number instead of overflow error exception?

Comment: @mattsmith5 Mostly precedent, I suppose. That’s what the languages that inspired Java (Smalltalk, C++) did.

Answer (score 9):

Lets look at the binary:

1000000 is `1111 0100 0010 0100 0000`.
1000000000000 is `1110 1000 1101 0100 1010 0101 0001 0000 0000 0000`

However, the first two sections of 4 bits *won't fit* in an `int` (since `int` is 32-bits wide in Java,) and so they are dropped, leaving only `1101 0100 1010 0101 0001 0000 0000 0000`, which is `-727379968`.

In other words, the result overflows for `int`, and you get what's left.

Comment: so curious, why did Java library decide to show a negative number instead of overflow error exception?

Answer (score 8):

You might want to check [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) as a general concept.
Overflow and underflow are handled differently depending on the language, too. Here is an article on [Integer overflow and underflow in Java](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-overflow-and-underflow/).

As for the reason why this is so in the Java language, as always, it's a tradeoff between simplicity in the language design and performance. But in [Java puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) (puzzle 3), the authors criticize the fact that overflows are silent in Java:

> **The lesson for language designers is that it may be worth reducing the
>   likelihood of silent overflow**. This could be done by providing support
>   for arithmatic that does not overflow silently. Programs could throw
>   an exception instead of overflowing, as does Ada, or they could switch
>   to a larger internal representation automatically as required to avoid
>   overflow, as does Lisp. Both of these approaches may have performance
>   penalties associated with them. Another way to reduce the likelyhood
>   of silent overflow is to support target typing, but this adds
>   significant complexity to the type system.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other answers explain correctly why this is happening (ie. signed two's compliment binary logic).

The actual solution to the problem and how to get the correct answer in Java when using really big numbers is to use the BigInteger class, which also works for long values.

```
package com.craigsdickson.scratchpad;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntegerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int bigInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        // prints incorrect answer
        System.out.println(bigInt * bigInt);

        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(bigInt);
        // prints correct answer
        System.out.println(bi.multiply(bi));

        long bigLong = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        // prints incorrect answer
        System.out.println(bigLong * bigLong);

        BigInteger bl = BigInteger.valueOf(bigLong);
        // prints correct answer
        System.out.println(bl.multiply(bl));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why integer overflow occurs have already been explained in other answers.

A practical way to ensure long arithmetic in calculations is to use numeric literals with `l` suffix that declare the literals as `long`.

Ordinary integer multiplication that overflows:

```
jshell> 100000 * 100000
$1 ==> -727379968
```

Multiplication where one of the multiplicands has `l` suffix that does not overflow:

```
jshell> 100000 * 100000l
$1 ==> 1000000000000
```

Note that `long`s are also prone to overflow, but the range is much greater, from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.