# Recursive function to calculate combination and factorial

Tags: java, recursion, long-integer

I am using the following two functions to calculate factorials and combinations.

```
public static long Factorial(long n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * Factorial(n-1);

}

public static long combinations (long n, long k)
{       
    return Factorial(n)/(Factorial(k) * Factorial(n - k));      
}
```

I am testing it using:

```
long test = combinations((long)21, (long)13);
```

It seems to work for small numbers such as `5,2`. But if I try `21,13`, I get incorrect answers (negatives or 0).

Would anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: What language/platform is this?

Comment: Your answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java

Comment: Not sure cause I don't feel like calculating it, but I'm pretty sure you're running into an overflow condition. Basically, long doesn't have enough capacity to hold the extremely large number that is 21 factorial and possibly 13 factorial. For large numbers like these, use BigInteger class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value of `long` in java is 2^63.

That will safely take you up to the factorial of 20. However, factorial of 21 comes to around 2^65, so you are exceeding the maximum value that can be represented.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215411/multiplication-of-two-ints-overflowing-to-result-in-a-negative-number) for a discussion about what happens in java if you perform a multiplication that results in an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly because of overflow from `long` (64bit signed). You can look up [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for use in this case.

Comment: BigInteger would be more appropriate

Comment: You need division to happen.

Comment: I saw he was using using long division, so I figured that's what he wanted. You could use both as well: BigInteger for factorial, and BigDecimal for combinations. Extra credit for one that uses long, detects overflow, and upgrades when necessary

Answer (score 0):

As other users have said long can't hold Factorial(21). I rewrote your Factorial method using BigInteger and it seems to work, although you have to pass a BigInteger in as the parameter.

```
public static BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger n)
{

    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    else
        return  n.multiply(Factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

Then rewrite your combinations method using BigInteger:

```
public static BigInteger combinations (BigInteger n, BigInteger k)
{  
        return Factorial(n).divide(Factorial(k).multiply(Factorial(n.subtract(k))));

}
```

In the main method I called the combinations method like this

```
System.out.print(combinations(new BigInteger("21"), new BigInteger("13")));
```